# what's wrong with following razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

```
@for (int counterA = 0; counterA < TotalIterations; counterA++)
{
    <tr>
    @for (int DayCounter = (counterA * 10); DayCounter <= ((counterA + 1) * 10) - 1; DayCounter++)
    {
        <td>a

        @{
            string @isCurrent = "0";
            if (1 == 1)
            {
            }
        }
        </td>
    }
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What your code actually does and what should it do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is likely the problem:

```
string @isCurrent = "0";
```

There's no need to put an `@` here. Just write:

```
string isCurrent = "0";
```